# How to print the list of the first ten data in XML

Tags: java, parsing, xpath

Currently I get only the first one DisplayName with Reputation > 100. How can I print the 10 first DisplayName? 
Like an output I want to get a list of the 10 first DisplayName with Reputation > 100.

Here is my Main file:

```
String output = (String) xPath.evaluate(
    "/users/row[@Reputation>'100']/@DisplayName", 
    doc2.getDocumentElement(),
    XPathConstants.STRING);
System.out.println("DisplayName for user with Reputation > 100: " + output);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `position()` syntax

```
/users/row[@Reputation>'100' and position() < 11]/@DisplayName
```

as per [Xpath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp):

> /bookstore/book[position()<3]
>
> Selects the first two book elements that are children of the bookstore element

Answer (score 0):

xPath.evaluate can return various object types.  This is controlled by the third parameter, which you have specified as "XPathConstants.STRING".

I believe you are looking for XPathConstants.NODESET, eg.:

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/users/row[@Reputation>'100']/@DisplayName", doc2.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I leave it to you to look up the API for XPath NodeSet.